# Facebook Open graph - scheduled post through api is not visible to other admins

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm successfully able to post to a Facebook fan page that I'm an admin for using the Open Graph api using a non expiring Page Access token I created from my account. When I go into Facebook's Publishing tools I'm able to see the scheduled post within the interface, but other admins of the fan page do not see the scheduled post. When scheduling posts using the native tools, all admins see the scheduled post in the list of scheduled posts.

Is there a way to schedule a post using a Page Access Token, but have the scheduled post visible to all admin users when they check the native Scheduled Posts interface?

Answer (score 0):

To make these scheduled posts visible to other users in the native scheduled post interface, I needed to go into the "status and review" section of my application settings and set the app and all of its live features to be accessible to the general public.

[image: Facebook App Settings]